# 行ってこなかった meaning

Tags: meaning

> **筆記試験の重要性は今更説明するまでもないが、学校はこれまで、体育祭や合宿くらいなもので他学年との交流を深くは行ってこなかった。**

It was a sentence from a light novel **ようこそ実力至上主義の教室へ** that I'm reading at this moment. The school is going to hold a special exam where the second grade students have to pair-up with the first grade students to face a written tests, and it was a new kind of exam where the students from a different academic year were involved as a team. The above-mentioned sentence was spoken by the homeroom teacher towards the students.

If I translated the sentence in english, it will be like: "I don’t need to explain the importance of the written test to you once again, but the school (**行ってこなかった**) friendly interaction with the other academic years, only during the Sports Festival and the Training Camp so far."

I read from [here](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0-kurai-no-mono-da-meaning/) that **くらいのものだ** means '**only**', and **のもの** can also be interchanged with **なもの**. That's why I would translate **くらいなもので** as '**only during**'. (it fits with the situation in the story, but I wondered if I have interpreted it properly)

I'm confused with the meaning of **行ってこなかった** in that sentence, is it came from **行く** or **行う**? And it was the students who didn't have much friendly interaction with the students from the other academic years, not the school itself. But that sentence mentioned the school instead of the students, it makes me doubt whether I have made a wrong interpretation of that sentence.

Please kindly give me your guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 行って is not いって but おこなって ("to do/conduct/perform"). 行く and 行う look the same in the te-/ta-form in kanji, but 交流を行く does not make sense because 交流 is not a place. Its subject is the school itself, not the students.

This (-て)くる after おこなう is a subsidiary verb that roughly means "until today", "over time", etc (see: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010) and [What are the subtleties of "て Form＋くる"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24962/5010)).

> 学校はこれまで、体育祭や合宿くらいなもので他学年との交流を深くは行ってこなかった。
>   We only had the Sports Festival and the Camp; (aside from them) our school has not engaged in inter-grade activities deeply (until today).

Comment: Maybe it'd be useful to try to say why it could not be 行く.

Comment: @Ringil Edited that part. Does it look better now?

Comment: Yup, thanks for adding it!